# how to stop dockerized nginx in foreground from flooding logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, supervisord

I'm running nginx and unicorn in a docker container managed by supervisord.
So, supervisord is the docker command. It in turn spawns nginx and unicorn. Unicorn talks to nginx over a socket. nginx listens on port 80.

I also have a logspout docker container running, basically piping all the docker logs to papertrail  by listening to docker.sock.

The problem is nginx is constantly spewing thousands of mundane entries to the logs:

`172.31.45.231 - - [25/May/2016:05:53:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 12961 0.0090`

I'm trying to disable it.

So far I've:

1. set `access_logs /dev/null;` in `nginx.conf` and vhost files.
2. tried to tell supervisord to stop logging the requests

   [program:nginx]
   command=bash -c "/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
   stdout_logfile=/dev/null
   stderr_logfile=/dev/null
3. tried to tell supervisord to send the logs to syslog not stdout:

   [program:nginx]
   command=bash -c "/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
   stdout_logfile=syslog
   stderr_logfile=syslog
4. Set log level in Unicorn to Warn in the rails code, and via env var.

Full supervisord conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=warn


[program:unicorn]
command=bundle exec unicorn -c /railsapp/config/unicorn.rb
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
redirect_stderr=true


[program:nginx]
command=bash -c "/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
stdout_logfile=/dev/null
stderr_logfile=/dev/null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try and [change nginx log level](https://serverfault.com/q/318574/783) with a:

```
access_log  off;
```

The goal remains to modify the `nginx.conf` used by the nginx image.